# p-adic cubic root

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be prime such that $p\equiv  2\bmod 3$. Show that for every $a\in \mathbb Z,p\nmid a$ there is a $x\in \mathbb Z_p$, where $\mathbb Z_p$ is the field of the p-adic integers, such that $x^3=a$.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_p$ is the *ring* of $p$-adic integers, $\Bbb Q_p$ is the field of $p$-adic numbers. Do you have any thoughts or ideas or attempts or work to show? Did Hensel's lemma work?

Comment: @blue, what i need to find,i think, is a solution of $x^3\equiv a \bmod p$ and then use Hensel's lemma. Need help to find such a solution.

Comment: think about the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^\times$

Comment: @hunter ,yes $a$ ahs an inverse in there. any help next?

Answer (score 3):

Hint (already given in comments): Hensel's lemma reduces to showing all elements of $\Bbb F_p^\times$ are cubes, which follows easily from $3\nmid(p-1)$. Can you see why?

Perhaps you'd get what's going on if I state it in a more general form: if $G$ is a finite group with order $n$ and $m$ is any number coprime to $n$, then $x\mapsto x^m$ must be a bijection on $G$. (Why?)

Comment: yes, because the derivate in hensel's lemma won't be zero. But how do i show that there is a $x:x^3\equiv a \bmod p$?

Comment: @user113576 Did you read my answer?

Comment: $|F_p|^*=p-1$ and because $3\nmid p-1$ then there isn't an elemnt with order $3$